# Как не потерять фокус выделенного объекта в DataGrid

Tags: wpf

Суть вопроса следующая, создан DataGrid и при выделении Item через

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF27798B" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2">
            <Grid>
                <Button/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

добавляются данные к примеру с кнопкой.
При нажатии на кнопку я текущий Item хочу удалить, но так как фокус пропадает при нажатии на кнопку то соответственно и удалить я не могу.

Comment: Причем если удаление привязать к простой кнопке вне датагрида то все отрабатывает нормально.

Comment: не ясно о чем вы спрашиваете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пусть у меня в DataGrid отображается некая коллекция товаров:

```
public ObservableCollection<ProductVm> Products { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<ProductVm>()
{
    new ProductVm { Name = "Молоко", Cost = 59.9m },
    new ProductVm { Name = "Хлеб", Cost = 25.0m },
    new ProductVm { Name = "Огурцы", Cost = 130.0m },
    new ProductVm { Name = "Чай", Cost = 85.9m }
};
```

Заведем команду для удаления элемента из коллекции:

```
public DelegateCommand DeleteCommand { get; }
```

И создадим ее в конструкторе:

```
DeleteCommand = new DelegateCommand(o => Products.Remove((ProductVm)o));
```

Команда очень простая, она получает в параметре товар и удаляет его из коллекции. Остается только передать этот товар в команду, это очень просто, т.к. как и любой ItemsControl, DataGrid устанавливает своим строкам DataContext и мы можем получить его с помощью привязки (обратите внимание на установку свойства `CommandParameter`):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Удалить" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю. Вся проблема у меня заключалась в биндинге. По вашему примеру все работает :) В моем случае я просто выполнял бинд к делегату и все. :) Еще раз спасибо