# C# WPF биндинг к методу коллекции

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть например ObservableCollection забиндена к ListBox ItemsSource и каждый ListBoxItem имеет свой шаблон и стиль с кнопочкой удаления. Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопочку удаления нужно удалить ListBoxItem и Object из коллекции. Как сделать биндинг к ObservableCollection.Remove и скормить ему нужный Object? Просто биндить каждому item delegate command и задавать метод в который бросать линк на всю коллекцию я не считаю правильным. item должна убивать коллекция и у него не должно быть доступа к всей коллекции.

Comment: Как вариант - сделайте каждому итему коллекции событие, при добавление в коллекцию делайте подпись, ну и в обработчике удаляйте из  коллекции нужные данные. Подобное можно посмотреть в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/836176/Удаление-кнопок-по-времени/836187#836187) ответе.

Comment: *Просто биндить каждому item delegate command и задавать метод в который бросать линк на всю коллекцию я не считаю правильным.* — вроде нормальное решение, передаем текущий элемент параметром и главная vm удаляет этот элемент

Comment: @АндрейNOP т.е. сделать в view model метод который удалит из коллекции нас тем самым не дав нам доступа к самой колекции?

Comment: Да, примерно как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/804891/218063